# drawing app for create draw triangle tool

Tags: javascript

Now I have the below code for me to draw the triangle, but the shape expand direction is not what I want. I would like to have the equilateral triangle expand symmetrically from the mouse position. How should I adjust this?

```
function DrawTriangle() {
    this.icon = "assets/triangle.jpg";
    this.name = "DrawTriangle";
    this.color = "black"; // Default color is black

    var startTriX = -1;
    var startTriY = -1;
    var drawingTri = false;

    this.draw = function() {
        if (mouseIsPressed) {
            if (startTriX == -1) {
                startTriX = mouseX;
                startTriY = mouseY;
                drawingTri = true;
                loadPixels();
            } else {
                updatePixels();
                stroke(this.color); // Set the stroke color to the selected color
                strokeWeight(5);
                // Calculate the height of an equilateral triangle
                var triHeight = (mouseX - startTriX) * Math.sqrt(3) / 2;
                // Draw an equilateral triangle using the mouse position as the third vertex
                triangle(startTriX, startTriY, mouseX, mouseY, startTriX + (mouseX - startTriX) / 2, startTriY + triHeight);
                noFill();
            }
        } else if (drawingTri) {
            drawingTri = false;
            startTriX = -1;
            startTriY = -1;
        }
    }
}
```